# Как переделать формат даты, приходящей в ответе от сервера?

Tags: android, json, дата

Работаю с Api Yandex-погоды. В ответе от сервера приходит дата в формате "yyyy-mm-dd". Получаю её методом getDate(). Как отформатировать эту дату, чтобы на экране приложения она отображалась в виде "dd-mm-yyyy"?

Comment: Если это строка, то разделить ее на нужные блоки и переставить их местами.

Comment: А можно ли это как-нибудь сделать с использованием класса SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: Да наверняка можно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String serverDate = "2020-03-11";
DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date = originalFormat.parse(serverDate);
String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date); 
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, всё работает!

Comment: Ну нельзя же идти на поводу у автора и могилку попугайчику копать экскаватором :)

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja конкретно в этом случае - да, но способ универсальный - преобразование любого паттерна даты в другой, включая преобразование, например, месяца чисом в месяц названием или добавление, например, дня недели и проч. Этот способ больше подходит для проблемы в заголовке.

Comment: Согласен, увидел бы такой комментарий в ответе -- нет вопросов.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так проще (Котлин)

```
val serverDate = "2020-03-11"
val fixedDate = serverDate.split("-").reversed().joinToString("-")
println(fixedDate) // 11-03-2020
```

На Java все тоже самое, будет просто больше кода.